# To what extent can the measures of the properties of data sets restrict the possibility of what they can be?

Tags: statistics

Despite the trivial cases, such as 1,1 and 1,1,1, can there be two different sets of data that have the same central tendency and dispersion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sets of data" perhaps implies *finite* lists of numbers.

Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_m$ are two such lists.

Let $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ be the respective sample means and let $s_x$ and $s_y$ be the sample standard deviations.

Then $\left( \dfrac{x_i-\bar x}{s_x} : i = 1,\ldots,n \right)$ and $\left( \dfrac{y_i-\bar y}{s_y} : i = 1,\ldots,m \right)$ have the same "central tendency" (i.e. sample mean), which is $0$, and the same dispersion, i.e. the same standard deviation, which $\text{is } 1$.

Now suppose we want some other mean, say $73$, and some other standard deviation, say $14$.  Then we can use $\left( 73 + 14 \dfrac{x_i-\bar x}{s_x} : i = 1,\ldots,n \right)$ and $\left( 73 + 14 \dfrac{y_i-\bar y}{s_y} : i = 1,\ldots,m \right)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By "measure of central tendency", I am referring to mode, median, and mean. By "measure of dispersion", I am referring to IQR and STD. How do you ensure the same mode and median?

Comment: Assuring the same median and interquartile range would take a bit more work.  The mode doesn't seem important since in a finite data set it may be typical that every value appears just once, so they're all modes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example: the data 1, 2, 3, 6 have mean 3 and SD 2.16.
And so do the data 0, 3, 4, 5. One dataset is the mirror
image of the other.

These two datsets have same same absolute deviations
$|X_i - \bar X|$ from the mean $\bar X = 3,$ but in the opposite order.
You can use this idea to make examples of larger sizes.

That's just for matching the means and the SDs. But you used generic terms 'central 
tenency' and 'dispersion'.  Here is a modification of the previous example in which both datasets have the same mean, median, and (not shown in Minitab printouts) mode.
Also the same variance, SD, IQR, range, and (not shown) mean absolute deviation.

```
 Data Display 

  Row  x  y
    1  1  0
    2  2  3
    3  3  3
    4  3  3
    5  3  4
    6  6  5

 Descriptive Statistics: x, y 

 Variable  N   Mean  SE Mean  StDev  Variance  Median  Range    IQR
 x         6  3.000    0.683  1.673     2.800   3.000  5.000  2.000
 y         6  3.000    0.683  1.673     2.800   3.000  5.000  2.000
```

For populations instead of datasets, the random variables
$X \sim Norm(\mu=3, \sigma=3)$ and $Y \sim Exp(mean=3)$ have $E(X) = E(Y) = SD(X) = SD(Y) = 3.$ Large samples from these distributions will *tend* to have sample means and SDs that match the corresponding population values. Graphs of their densities are
shown below.

[image]

Here are sample means and SDs for random samples of size $n = 100,000$ from each
distribution (simulated in R).

```
 x = rnorm(10^5, 3, 3); mean(x); sd(x)
 ## 2.996163  # Approx E(X) = 3
 ## 2.99926   # Approx SD(X) = 3
 y = rexp(10^5, 1/3); mean(y); sd(y)  # rate 1/3 implies mean 3 & SD 3
 ## 3.006326  # Approx E(Y) = 3
 ## 3.007839  # approx SD(Y) = 3
```

Comment: (Sorry about copying and pasting the comment.) Thank you for the answer. By "measure of central tendency", I am referring to mode, median, and mean. By "measure of dispersion", I am referring to IQR and STD. How do you ensure the same mode and median?

Comment: In the contrived dataset 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6 (and its 'mirror' image) I ensured mean, median, and mode are the same by having repeated 3's. The huge simulated datasets could (with fussing) be adjusted to have the same means and medians, because that is the nature of the populations. For large samples from continuous dist'n, there are $no$ repeated values (if you carry enough decimal places), so one takes the mode to be where density function (or est. of it) reaches its maximum.// If you have what you need, how about "Accepting" one of the Answ. Otherwise leave Comment w/ add'l questions.